# PageNavi redirects to 404 when used as archive page

Tags: plugins, pagination, 404-error, archive-template, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I'm using a page as archive for a custom post type called **event**.

```
register_post_type('event', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Événements',
        'singular_name' => 'Événement',
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
    'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => false,
        'slug' => 'evenements'
    )
));
```

Then, I defined this page template to **template-event.php**, where I use the following code to loop through post types.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged'          => get_query_var('paged')
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        the_title();

    endwhile;

    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $the_query ) );
    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
?>
```

This code works great for my **home.php** page, but not for this one.
Any idea why?

Comment: Is there a reason you are creating a new query in the template instead of using the default main query? This is the source of your problem- you can’t paginate a custom query beyond the number of pages in the main query in an archive.

Comment: @Milo I'm using a new query because I need to order posts and use `meta_query` for showing only those which have a ACF date bigger than the current date.

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts` to alter main query arguments.

Comment: @milo The default main query doesn't work since I'm using a **page** as archive.

Comment: Pagination pattern for singular views is `slug/n/`, not `slug/page/n/`, and query var is `page` what nstead of `paged`